# Is sudo -u username command the same as doing sudo -i -u username then command?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

Is a terminal prompt `sudo -u username command`

same as doing

`sudo -i -u username` then `command` in the next line?

If no, what is the differences? What are the use cases when doing the first is better or preferable than doing the later and vice versa.

If anyone could explain what the command do step by step or  parameter per parameter, that is even better.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -u username command:
```

This command runs the specified command as the specified username. It does not change the current working directory or the environment variables

```
sudo -i -u username:
```

This command opens an interactive login shell as the specified username. It changes the current working directory to the home directory of the specified user and sets up the environment variables as if you were logging in as that user.

Basically `sudo -u username` command is better for running a single command as another user without changing the environment or creating a new shell whereas `sudo -i -u username` is better for running multiple commands in a new shell with the environment of the specified user.